# Google API error handling cant get error message

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

Google calendar API returns error for invalid event ids I used try catch for error handling but the error response come as a object as below,

```
Google_Service_Exception Object
(
    [errors:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [domain] => global
                    [reason] => deleted
                    [message] => Resource has been deleted
                )

        )

    [retryMap:Google_Service_Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [500] => -1
            [503] => -1
            [rateLimitExceeded] => -1
            [userRateLimitExceeded] => -1
        )

    [message:protected] => Error calling DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/qdkeiablias0t17vn3kh5aopq0_20160614T000000Z: (410) Resource has been deleted
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 410
    [file:protected] => C:\xampp\htdocs\sys-feedback\application\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php
    [line:protected] => 110
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
```

How can I get the **`message`** using php...

I used JSON DECODE as well but it returns nothing

```
foreach ($event_ids as $eventID):
        try {
            $this->service->events->delete('primary', $eventID);
        } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {


        }


    endforeach;
    $result = json_decode($e,true);
    print_r($result;
```

when I do  `echo $e['errors'][0]['message'];` it returns  `Cannot use object of type Google_Service_Exception as array in`

Answer (score 4):

For the title of the bug you can do `$e->getMessage()`:

```
try {
    $this->service->events->delete('primary', $eventID);
} catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $e->getMessage();           // This works
    print_r($e->getErrors());   // Not sure yet, have to test
}
```

As said, about the `$e->getErrors()`, I'm not sure yet, still have to try that.